# Azure: How does the CDN work together with an Application gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cdn

I have a web app which has a decent amount of static content: images, css, some js etc. I was trying to figure out how to deliver those resources.

My first thought was using the storage + CDN setup yet, I would be running into issues since I'm also using a Zuul Proxy as an Application Gateway.

Therefore, if every request goes through the gateway, the gateway itself needs to be replicated across regions and cache content in order to achieve the same performance as a CDN, right?

If this is the case, how does the Azure Application Gateway integrate with it's CDN? Does it maintain the performance of the CDN or drastically lowers it?

***Edit***

Also, if I have both the Application Gateway and the CDN replicated so much, is it even worth having a CDN? Wouldn't activating some caching rules inside the gateway do the trick?

Comment: How much of your traffic is static content? Also what do you mean by 'activating some caching rules inside the gateway'? Are you referring here to Azure App Gateway or caching on the Zuul Proxy level?

Comment: @LechMigdal Hey, when I was first considering this question I though that the CDN should go behind the API Gateway to my sistem. Since then I've realised that if I put it infront of it, and make the CDN the entry to my system everything actually makes sense :)

Comment: @LechMigdal I've the same question too. If the CDN in front of App Gateway, how the non static resources are managed?